# Custom Pelican theme not rendering

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

In order to help me get some experience with CSS, HTML and Bootstrap I made a super quick blog with Pelican and I am trying to make my own template. I started with a few lorum posts just to have something.

Following multiple tutorials and reading for the last several hours, I created a theme directory in my project and placed a template directory in that.

I created a very simple `base.html` and `index.html` in the template directory.

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is my base template</h2>

        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ SITENAME }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ SITENAME }}</h1>
    {% for article in articles %}
        <h2><a href="/{{ article.slug }}.html">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
        <label>Posted on <strong>{{ article.date }}</strong></label> 
        {{ article.content|truncate(110) }}
    {% else %}
        No posts yet!
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I set `THEME = 'theme'` in `pelicanconf.py`. I have tried generating my site with `make html` and with `pelican content -s pelicanconf.py -t theme` but it just won't generate using my `base.html` and `index.html` files.

Comment: That should be sufficient, as you can see from [an earlier commit in my own Pelican blog](https://github.com/textbook/textbook.github.io-source/tree/1cba47e6f11633542540fb120fc5d1c0645b71e4) setting `THEME = 'directory'` and having `directory/templates/base.html` should lead to that template getting used. Is it a typo - `template` vs. `templates`? Could you show a [mcve] of the setup?

Comment: Oh my lord!  It was 'template' vs 'templates' .  I can not believe it was so simple!  Thank you so much